# Como acessar uma propriedade do elemento Event em Javascript?

Tags: javascript, typescript, javascript-eventos

Acredito ser uma dúvida boba, mas pelo meu conhecimento iniciante estou me batendo um pouco. Estou construindo um aplicativo em ionic3, este usa typescript, porém o plugin que estou trabalhando usa javascript puro. No meu console consigo exibir todas as propriedades de "event", mas como eu faço para exibir uma propriedade específica dessas ? A propriedade que preciso está grifada em amarelo "rewardAmount".

[image: Aqui está a imagem do meu console, o que preciso é deste destacado em amarelo]

```
    videosAdColony() {
    let carregar = this.loading.create({content : "Carregando..."});
    carregar.present();
    let rewardConfig: AdMobFreeRewardVideoConfig = {
        isTesting: true,
        autoShow: true,
        id: 'ca-app-pub-8000726989219599/8229278077' //id videos AdColony
    };
    this.admob.rewardVideo.config(rewardConfig);
    this.admob.rewardVideo.prepare().then(() => {
        console.log('video adcolony executado com sucesso');
        carregar.dismissAll();
        document.addEventListener('admob.rewardvideo.events.REWARD', function (event) {

            console.log(event);
        })
    })
}
```

Comment: O que retorna em `console.log(event.rewardAmount);` e `console.log(event.prototype.rewardAmount);`?

Comment: Ele me retorna um erro de sintaxe, e não permite que eu rode o aplicativo para teste. Em ambos comandos

Comment: Consegui resolver usando : 
console.log(event['rewardAmount']);

Comment: Insira a sua solução na resposta abaixo ;)

Answer (score 0):

Se for um array: event['nome_do_campo']

Se for um objeto: event.nome_do_campo

Se for um array de objeto: event[0].nome_do_campo